# How do I determine the best amount of money to spend on any given campaign?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy

So I'm using `sklearn`'s linear model `ElaticNet` and `GridSearch` to find the coefficients for Spend, Visits, Clicks, and LFA's (Lower Funnel Actions). I'm predicting Spend to Clicks, then the prediction of Clicks to Visits, then Visits to LFA's. LFA's are the most important thing for the company that I am working for. What I want to do is find out what the best amount of money (Spend) is to maximize the LFA's. The problem is not one of "spend more get more" because on Google there are only so many people searching for the product, on a website there are only so many people that visit, and blogs etc it's the same deal.

Let's say that we pay $150,000 on Google Advertisements and we get 100,000 LFA's. If we spend $200,000 and get 110,000 LFA's, obviously it's not worth it (diminishing returns). We just spent another $50,000 (an increase of 50%) to get 10% more LFA's. To us, $150,000 is the best amount of money to spend because as time goes on, people remember the brand and we eventually get that 110,000 LFA's anyway.

Is there an automated way that I can determine what the best amount of money I should spend is for the maximizing the number of LFA's before the clicks and visits cap out or start diminishing?

Data examples-

[image: Search Example]

[image: Digital Example]

Please note that most of the data doesn't have a value in the field for weeks.

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that LFA's happen only because of money spent on Google Ads (`GA`)? The point is let's say there is another factor (call it `FX`) which also influences the LFA's. In that case what you are looking at is a combined effect of `FX` and `GA`. If you have access to other forms of promotional expenses, then you might want to incorporate that in the analysis as well.

Comment: There's no other promotional expenses. Just, for example, there are 27 weeks documented for the 'AR-5C-Tier 1-Bing Ads-Retention' campaign. I'm using all 27 of those records and using Spend to predict Clicks, Clicks to predict Visits, and then Visits to predict LFA's. You MUST, unless you've arrived to the destination by choice, click on the ad, visit the campaign site, and then do your LFA (which is, let's say, building your own t-shirt). There is also a 'Channel' of either Search or Digital. Search is like the one I mentioned, Digital is like 'AR-ARB-Shopper-AOL-Endemic-Direct'. Make sense?

Comment: Ok. What does your data look like? Could you please share some dummy data?

Comment: What is the smallest unit of your data? a single instance of LFA? The problem you are trying solve is an optimization problem: _minimize Ad-Expense, but maximize LFA's_.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm adding a snippet of the input data.

Comment: Can you explain what the second table is for? I suppose the second column in that table is not week number?!

Comment: Food for thought: you could think of this as a stacked/chained Bayesian model. Given X happens, what is the probability of y? And then you can chain them. P(Spend)P(Clicks|Spend)P(Visits|Clicks)P(LFAs|Visits) = P(y)

Comment: Another option for you: use Decision Trees. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html

Comment: Thanks Cypher! The second table does have weeks in there but the column must be hidden. There's no values in that column. Can what you described predict how to get a 5% increase in LFA's with a minimum Spend? If so, do you think you can write some code so I can mark an answer and up vote?

Comment: Currently the way you have it set up, you are trying to predict the posterior probability (probability of LFA's given a certain Ad-spend). But if you want to predict the required amount of Ad-spend for a given LFA (present + 5% increase), then form the problem the other way around: given LFA what is required Ad-spend.

Comment: It seems pretty simple doesn't it? The problem is that we need to predict how many clicks and visits we are going to get as well... which in my opinion is worthless. I've tried to convince them to use MLP and RandomForestRegressors, and both have come out significantly more accurate, but they want ease of explanations and coefficients. Right now we are making X = ['Spend', 'root_Spend'] etc. Then y = clicks, visits, or LFA's.

Comment: What I really want to do is use the MLP Regressor and Random Forests and just say here look at this, it's 99% confident that if you spend X you will get Y+5%. But that would mean no graphs and no coefficients and possibly no minimization/optimization.